# How to use flask variables from outside the function to later use in javascript?

Tags: python, flask

Running routes.py

```
@app.route('/articles', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def articles():
    upload()
    return render_template('articles.html')
```

And this function that saves an image and processes its information

```
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Save the file to static/uploads
    
        label = "some string from process above"
        probability = "another string"

        return None

    return None
```

How do I make use of the variables label and probability in rendering the template? Some people use something close to:

```
return render_template('articles.html', label=label, probability=probability)
```

This would be done to make a reference to variables using js. But how do I make a reference to that variable if it is computed inside of upload()? Any need for global variables?

Comment: You can return those variables from the function.

Comment: if i return them like return label, probability will I be able to use them directly somewhere else or i should instead define label, probability = upload() ?

Comment: You have to unpack the variable you are sending from function, so first, you have to return them from `upload` and then unpack it to send it to `render_template`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return those variables from the function.

You have to unpack the variable you are sending from `upload` function.

First, you have to return them from `upload` and then unpack it to send it to `render_template`.

```
@app.route('/articles', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def articles():
    label, probability = upload()
    return render_template('articles.html', label=label, probability=probability)
```

```
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Save the file to static/uploads
    
        label = "some string from process above"
        probability = "another string"

        return (label, probability)

    return (None, None)
```

Comment: Thanks, now html/javascript id for each will be the names specified in render_template() right?

Comment: I am not sure about what is `id` here?

Comment: For example, it will be easy to use <h3 id="label"></h3> and have the text in label be displayed?

Comment: Yes, you can certainly do that by using something like this `{{ label }}`